# Print list content in a given order

Tags: python, list, python-2.7, for-loop

```
lt = ['7,777.7', '777.7', '77,777.7', '77.7']
```

How can I proceed to print the list content like this ?

```
 7,777.7
   777.7
77,777.7
    77.7
```

Comment: why the downvotes on this question? It seems..ok?

Comment: @Untitled123 it shows no research effort.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [rjust](http://python-reference.readthedocs.org/en/latest/docs/str/rjust.html#rjust):

```
>>> length = len(max(lt,key=len))
>>> for i in lt:
...     print i.rjust(length)
...
 7,777.7
   777.7
77,777.7
    77.7
```

Comment: Why not just `length = max(map(len, lt))`?

Answer (score 1):

Something like this:

```
>>> max_len = max(lt, key=len)
>>> for i in lt:
    print ' '*(len(max_len)-len(i)) + i


 7,777.7
   777.7
77,777.7
    77.7
```

Answer (score 1):

Compute the maximum length of the strings in your list, then iterate over your list and `format` each item accordingly before you `print` it.

```
>>> lt = ['7,777.7', '777.7', '77,777.7', '77.7']
>>> maxlen = max(len(x) for x in lt) # get max length; here: 8
>>> for item in lt:
...     print '{0}{1}'.format((maxlen-len(item))*' ', item)
... 
 7,777.7
   777.7
77,777.7
    77.7
```